# resize pdf images using Image.getInstance

Tags: java, image, pdf, resize, itext

I have the following code. 
I'm trying to get instance of pdf pages as image, resize the images and then added back to the document.

```
for (int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages();i++){
          PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
          Image image = Image.getInstance(page);
          float currentWidth = image.getWidth();
          float currentHeight = image.getHeight();
          image.scalePercent(50);
          float newWidth = image.getWidth();
          float newHeight = image.getHeight();
}
```

I creates float variables to find the width and height of the image before and after scale. 
here is the problem i'm facing. the current and new height adn width are exactly the same. they don't change.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 float newWidth = image.getScaledWidth();
 float newHeight = image.getScaledHeight();
```

Comment: Great! BTW, it's considered nice to accept someone's answer if it helped you.

Comment: thanks for your help but still i can't fix the problem i'm facing. I'm trying to resize the pdf pages. I managed to resize the images but when i open the pdf file they are exactly the same size as before.

Comment: Sounds like you're not adding the image to the Writer object. Is there a possibility you could use the [PdfCopy](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html) class as shown here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=128 ?

Comment: I already tried PdfCopy and i didn't work. i tried to add the images using PdfCopy but no luck yet

Comment: To add content when using PdfCopy, you need a PageStamp object. Look for PageStamp in chapter 6 of my book: http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Comment: thanks for the comment. I used both of them to add the new pic. but still it adds the old pics.